# Recursive function that finds the number of binary strings of length N that starts with 0 and have odd sequences of 0s and 1s

Tags: c++, recursion, binary, sequence

> Describe a recursive function, that finds the number of binary strings of length N, which starts with 0 and have odd sequences of 0s and 1s.
>
> Sample Input 3
> Sample Output 2

I stumbled on this problem and can't quite wrap my head around it. An explanation of the approach to solve this/pseudo/real code would be really appreciated.

I came up with the following solution, though I'm not sure if the sequence counting is right.

```cpp
int find(int n, int i, string str, int seqN) {
    if (i == 0) {
        str.append("0");
        return find(n, i + 1, str, seqN);
    }
    if (n > i) {
        return find(n, i + 1, str+"1", seqN) + find(n, i + 1, str + "0", seqN);
    }
    if (n == i) {
        cout << str << "\n";
        string sub = "01";
        string sub2 = "10";
        int n = 0;
        n += countRecursive(str, sub);
        n += countRecursive(str, sub2);
       
        if (n%2 != 0)
        {
            return seqN + 1;
        }
    }
    return seqN;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "odd sequences of 0s and 1s"?

Comment: @Nick I had the same question -- the only explanation I can think of is _odd length_ sequences, i.e. there can be three zeroes in a row, or five, or seven, but never (just) two or four.

Comment: @JohnGordon or perhaps an odd *number* of sequences?

Comment: @Nick I don't know the question is phrased this way, that is the main part that confuses me, the only thing I found about "odd sequences" was this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddSequence.html

Comment: Not familiar with those... I'm not really sure how you would solve that with recursion. Will be interesting to see what answers you get...

Answer (score 0):

```
F(N-1) = 2F(N-2)
if statements:
F(1)=1
F(0)=0
```

starting with 0 for the length of 3 is exactly the same as  2 elements that are in odd sequence.
For example: 0001 - 010 which is F(3) but its exactly F(2) of recursive of finding only odd sequence. the logic is obvious because 0 doesn't influence the sum of sequence.
behind the scene for calculating by hand.
odd sequence in F(5) is counting 5 one in 5 places or 1 one in 5 places or 3 in 5 places. and its exactly 2^4 or 2^(n-1)